# App startup slowed: Unable to open '/system/framework/dpmapi.jar'

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, firebase

When my app is getting started up, I need to update the user **Firebase Id** based on login information. At the point when the details are being checked against the database, I get this output in the console and the app freezes for 8-10 seconds and sometimes up to 30 seconds.

The full console output is:

```
Unable to open '/system/framework/dpmapi.jar': No such file or directory
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/dpmapi.jar': I/O Error
```

The part of the code where this console output appears is:

```
if (d.appuserexists(email)==true) {
  d.appusermsgid(email,refreshedToken);
}
```

`d` is the Database instance hosted on **AWS** and `refreshedToken` is the **Firebase Id**.